# Given multiple dictionaries in a list, how to sum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Given multiple dictionaries in a list, and 3 keys (student id, subject id, valutation) in each dictionary:

I need to calculate the total valutation. Though, if there are multiple valutations in the same subject, I have to take in consideration exclusively the last one.
I found here on Stackoverflow a piece of code that could help me and I was trying to understand and modify It, but I can't. Thanks in advance for any help!

This is an example:

```
exams = [
        {'ID': 'p2', 'subject': 'am1', 'value': '18'},
        {'ID': 'p2', 'subject': 'in1', 'value': '30'},
        {'ID': 'p2', 'subject': 'am1', 'value':'23'},
        {'ID': 'p9', 'subject': 'am1', 'value': '30'},
        {'ID': 'p9', 'subject': 'in2', 'value': '30'},
        {'ID': 'p9', 'subject': 'dX4', 'value': '30'}
        ]

result = {}

req_key = 'student_id'
req_exam = 'exam_id'
for exam in exams:
    student_val = exam.pop(req_key)
    exam_val = exam.pop(req_exam)
    result.setdefault(student_val, {req_key: student_val})
    result.setdefault(exam_val, {req_exam: exam_val})
    for k, v in exam.items():
        result[student_val][k] = result[student_val].get(k, 0) + result[exam_val].get(k, 0) + int(v)
print(result)
```

Here It is a similar work, I was just trying to sum all values given 2 keys as "pivots".

This is my first time writing on StackOverflow sorry.
This is the expected output:

```
['p2', '53']
['p9', '90']
```

53 is the sum of each valutation for p2 (18 excluded), while
90 is the sum of each valutation for p9

Comment: Please read [mre]

Comment: please check your code and make sure it's reproducible. What is `esami`? WHat is the exact expected output?

Comment: @mozway I think `esami` is the list of dictionaries

Comment: @Barmar probably but what is the exact format? OP should provide a reproducible input

Comment: Is the variable `list` supposed to be `esami`? The values are sets, not dictionaries -- you're missing the keys.

Comment: Don't use `pop()`, use `esame[req_key]`

Comment: Please, post the expected result

Comment: Seems like you should be able to do something as simple as `sum({d['sub']: d['val'] for d in esami}.values())` -- building a dict keyed on subject will automatically just leave the last valuation, and then all you have to do is sum them.  The `d['sub']: d['val']` part needs to be updated for whatever your actual dicts look like, since your example doesn't show actual dicts.

Comment: @Samwise That doesn't handle duplicates as required.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what "exclusively the last one" means, but that *sounds* to me like they just want the valuation from the last dict in the list for a given subject, as opposed to doing some kind of aggregation.  When you build up a dict iteratively (including in a dict comprehension) and there are duplicate keys, the last one will overwrite the earlier ones, which conveniently makes this a one-liner.

Comment: If this is your actual code, you should probably use parentheses `( )` rather than curly braces `{ }` for the elements of `esami`, so that they are stored as tuples rather than sets. EDIT: Well, this comment no longer makes sense now that the question has been edited.

Comment: So now it should be as simple as: `esami_as_dict = {(entry['ID'], entry['subject']): int(entry['value']) for entry in esami}; total_valutation = sum(esami_as_dict.values())`

Comment: I edited some things, hope It's more clear now, thank you.

Comment: @Stef That's very interesting, I'll take It in consideration for the future. Though It doesn't give me the expected output. My fault. There's an expected output in the post now!

Comment: @Samwise Imagine the list in time order from top to bottom. 1° exam, 2° exam... if the "fourth" exam in the same subject has a better score than the previous ones, than It will be the only one that you'll take in consideration for the total sum

Comment: Ah. You said "total valutation", not "total valutation by student". Well, then you need to group by student: `esami_as_nested_dict = {}; for entry in esami: esami_as_nested_dict[entry['ID']][entry['subject']] = int(entry['value']); total_per_student = {student_id: sum(subdict.values()) for student_entry, subdict in esami_as_nested_dict.items()}; print(*([k, v] for k,v in total_per_student.items()), sep='\n')`

Comment: *"f the "fourth" exam in the same subject has a better score than the previous ones"* You never said anything about this big "if" before!!

Comment: It as complicate to exaplain even for me, sorry my bad. Hope It's all clear now

Answer (score 2):

You can use two steps:

```
esami = [
        {'ID': 'p2', 'subject': 'am1', 'value': '18'},
        {'ID': 'p2', 'subject': 'in1', 'value': '30'},
        {'ID': 'p2', 'subject': 'am1', 'value':'23'},
        {'ID': 'p9', 'subject': 'am1', 'value': '30'},
        {'ID': 'p9', 'subject': 'in2', 'value': '30'},
        {'ID': 'p9', 'subject': 'dX4', 'value': '30'}
        ]


# step 1: deduplicate
# keeping only the last occurrence per ID/subject
dic1 = {}
for d in esami:
    dic1[(d['ID'], d['subject'])] = d # keeping the whole dict here
                                      # you could keep only the value

# step 2: aggregate
total = sum(int(d['value']) for d in dic1.values())
# 143
```

You can also compress this logic into a single line:

```
total = sum({(d['ID'], d['subject']): int(d['value']) for d in esami}.values())
```

For a subtotal per ID:

```
total = {}
for d in dic1.values():
    total[d['ID']] = total.get(d['ID'], 0) + int(d['value'])
```

Output:

```
{'p2': 53, 'p9': 90}
```

Or:

```
from collections import Counter 

total = Counter()
for d in dic1.values():
    total[d['ID']] += int(d['value'])
```

Output:

```
Counter({'p9': 90, 'p2': 53})
```

Comment: I edited the answer for a subtotal per ID

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

esami = [
        {'ID': 'p2', 'subject': 'am1', 'value': '18'},
        {'ID': 'p2', 'subject': 'in1', 'value': '30'},
        {'ID': 'p2', 'subject': 'am1', 'value':'23'},
        {'ID' : 'p9', 'subject': 'am1', 'value': '30'},
        {'ID' : 'p9', 'subject': 'in2', 'value': '30'},
        {'ID' : 'p9', 'subject': 'dX4', 'value': '30'}
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(esami)

for _, group in df.groupby(["ID","subject"]):
    print(group.iloc[-1].values)
```

Which gives:

```
['p2' 'am1' '23']
['p2' 'in1' '30']
['p9' 'am1' '30']
['p9' 'dX4' '30']
['p9' 'in2' '30']
```

Now, instead of `print` you can append it to a list or make a new dictionary. That's up to you.

Comment: I disagree with this recommendation. The OP is already struggling with the syntax for lists and dicts and you want them to use pandas dataframes with groupby and iloc?

Comment: You're output is correct more or less, but as Stef stated before I would need to do It without importing any module. I'll show what should be my output now, sorry.

Comment: @Stef I see your point. I will keep this answer, though, as I think this is the preferred way for people in data analysis. It may be useful for other users.